# Custom control Tag

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am designing the custom control and there is a requirement as :

```
<Control:MyControl>

  <Control:MyControl.Property1>

       <Control:MyControl.Property2></Control:MyControl.Property2>

 </Control:MyControl.Property1>

</Control:MyControl>
```

Can you please suggest me the solution for this ?

Thank You

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to specify values for the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement the properties in your control as full properties, or even just auto-properties like this :

```
public object IAmAProperty {get; set;}
```

You can now define a value for this property from XAML :

```
<control:MyControl>
  <Control:MyControl.IAmAProperty>i am a value</Control:MyControl.IAmAProperty>
</control:MyControl>
```

However i should warn that this:

```
<Control:MyControl.Property1>
       <Control:MyControl.Property2></Control:MyControl.Property2>
 </Control:MyControl.Property1>
```

is **not** going to work . (Property2 of MyControl cannot be nested inside Property1 of MyControl)